# How to vagrant ssh to different guest prort

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I have vagrant vm centos 7 running ssh on XXXX port (not default 22)

How can I connect to XXXX port using "vagrant ssh" command

I tried this but did not work.

```
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2222, id: "ssh" , disabled: true
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: xxxx, host: 2223, auto_correct: true
  config.ssh.port = 2223
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend on the provider you're using, but setting `config.ssh.guest_port=XXXX` along with a port forwarding does the trick for me when using Virtualbox as a provider.

With that you shouldn't even have to specify `config.ssh.port`, as Vagrant will detect the port forwarding settings automatically.

See also [vagrantfile documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html#config-ssh-guest_port)

Answer (score 0):

Wandering what configuration @su_li used exactly, I tried different possibilities and the following code came to work as expected :

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 54321, host: 2222, id: "ssh"
config.ssh.guest_port = 54321
```

The guest OS (the VM) runs sshd on port 54321.
The host OS will send ssh request to port 2222.
With this configuration, all requests to port 2222 on the host side will be forwarded to port 54321 on the guest side.
And all responses from port 54321 from the guest side will be forwarded to port 2222 on the host side.

Note that the `id: "ssh"` part is necessary if you want to override the default ssh port forwarding configuration.